# How can I handle error as Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

My below view code in View is below

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Dashboard";    
    var StudentRequestTimedt = ViewBag.StudentRequestTime as DataTable;
    if (StudentRequestTimedt != null)
    {
        var StudentRequestTime = StudentRequestTimedt.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new
        {
            StudentRequestId = t.Field<int>("StudentRequestId"),
            FromTime = t.Field<string>("FromTime"),
            ToTime = t.Field<string>("ToTime"),
        }).ToList();
    }
    else
    { var StudentRequestTime = ""; }   
}

if (StudentRequestTime != "")
{
   var StudentRequestTimecount = StudentRequestTime.Where(d => d.StudentRequestId == StudentRequestId).ToList();
}
```

On writting this I am getting error as StudentRequestTime doesnot exist in the current context.

This issue comes in case I am returning ViewBag.StudentRequestTime as null from controller side

My controller side code is as

```
if (GetData.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0 && GetData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  ViewBag.StudentRequestTime = GetData.Tables[1];
 }
 else
 {
   ViewBag.StudentRequestTime = null;
 }
return View();
```

Please Also review this below image, Here I am getting data in multiple viewbag in this case how can I manage? var StudentRequestTime is null or empty
[image]

**How can I handle this issue ?**

**Updated code resolved my issue**

**Old code of controller**

```
if (GetData.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0 && GetData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  ViewBag.StudentRequestTime = GetData.Tables[1];
 }
 else
 {
   ViewBag.StudentRequestTime = null;
 }
return View();
```

**New Code of controller**

```
ViewBag.StudentRequestTime = GetData.Tables[1];
```

**On ViewSide**

[image]

Comment: That's because `StudentRequestTime` is locally scoped (only exists *within* the first if statement)

Comment: ^^^^^^. Define `StudentRequestTime` outside the `if`

Comment: What should I write outside the statement ??

var StudentRequestTime="";

Comment: @Xtremcool see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
if (eyeColor == EyeColor.Green)
{
    // greenEyeColorFound has been declared *in this if statement*,
    // so it only exists *within this if statement*
    var greenEyeColorFound = true;
}

// this will fail. greenEyeColorFound was declared *in the first if statement*,
// how can the if statement below be aware of it's existence?
if (greenEyeColorFound == true)
{       
    Debug.WriteLine("Found a person with green eyes!");
}
```

`greenEyeColorFound` is *locally scoped* to the first if statement. Only code *within* that if statement can be aware of it's existence.

To get my example to work, `greenEyeColorFound` should be accessible by *both* `if`s, which can be achieved by placing it's declaration outside of both `if`s:

```
// this is now declared *outside* of the two if statements,
// so both are now aware of it and can access it's value.
var greenEyeColorFound = false;
if (eyeColor == EyeColor.Green)
{
    greenEyeColorFound = true;
}

// presto, this now works
if (greenEyeColorFound == true)
{       
    Debug.WriteLine("Found a person with green eyes!");
}
```

This is the exact issue you are having with `StudentRequestTime`. Declare it *once* outside of the `if`s, then just set it's value in your if/else statements.

---

Since we're at it, I wouldn't use `ViewBag` at all, let alone have it carry `DataTable`s over to the Razor side. I would use viewmodels (read ["Accessing Your Model's Data from a Controller"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) over at Microsoft ASP.NET MVC docs to see how this works, in particular section "Strongly Typed Models and the `@model` Keyword") which are much cleaner and maintainable.

You can easily refactor your existing code to use viewmodels using the steps below:

1) Create a class, let's name it `StudentRequestTimeViewModel`:

```
public class StudentRequestTimeViewModel
{
    public int StudentRequestId { get; set; }
    public string FromTime { get; set; }
    public string ToTime { get; set; }
}
```

2) In your controller, populate a `List<StudentRequestTimeViewModel>`:

```
var studentRequestTimes = new List<StudentRequestTimeViewModel>();
if (GetData.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0 && GetData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // populate studentRequestTimes here        
}
// return the view, passing in studentRequestTimes as our model
return View(studentRequestTimes);
```

3) Your Razor then becomes:

```
/* your model is declared as "@model",
   but is accessed as "Model".         */
@model List<StudentRequestTimeViewModel>

@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
    /* your List<StudentRequestTimeViewModel> Model is not null or empty */
    foreach(var studentRequestTime in Model)
    {
        <p>Student with ID @studentRequestTime.StudentRequestId is here.</p>
    }
}
else
{
    /* your List<StudentRequestTimeViewModel> Model is null or empty */
}
```

Comment: Please review mu updated question where I had additional added my actual view layout

Comment: My answer was for your question "How can I handle error as Value cannot be null" - the updated question is a new question altogether, so you should ask that question in a new post. Also, from the screenshot, it looks like you haven't followed any of the suggestions proposed in the comments of your question and this answer itself.

Comment: You had asked me to call the model that relates to  StudentRequestTimeViewModel but I need to call model as StudentRequest

Comment: My question is how should I handle my viewbag and what should I assign so that it should work the flow, You asked me to create the model and do the following things, So that I uploaded my code image so that u understand what I actually mean to be

Comment: Also Update your answer as I had written in my question to mark you as answer, Also the way You had told is helpful to me so please don't delete that just add it.

Comment: The first piece of code in my answer explains what you need to do to solve your error. You need to move the *declaration* of `StudentRequestTime` (`var ...`) *outside* the `if` so you can access it further down the code path, and treat it as the *same type* everywhere. In your `else {}` part, you are setting `StudentRequestTime`  to `""` (i.e. a `string`), but you treat it as an enumeration elsewhere. Declare it outside of the `if`, then in your second `if` you can check if it's not `null` and that it's `.Count > 0` (treat it as an enumeration *everywhere* as it will never be a `string`).